# memcached on gae and compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I know most likely the answer will be no but I would still like to ask even if I searched.

Is there any way to be able to update the memcache of app engine from a compute engine? I am using dedicated memcache for my appengine but I would like to be able to edit it also from a compute engine instance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple REST API on the AppEngine to GET/POST/PUT/DELETE entries in memcache.  Then call that API from your Compute Engine.  You could probably write this in Go or Python.

Comment: That's similar to what we are doing now but it will always add that unwanted overhead. Direct access is preferable

Comment: You may have to run your own memcached server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30688739/584846